# Year/Quarter to datetime datatype

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert the "Year_Quarter" column (object) to datetime64 datatype.Note there is a space between year and quarter.

```
          df
                 Year_Quarter
             0     2009 Q1
             1     2009 Q1
             2     2009 Q2
```

I tried the code below

```
       df['Year_Quarter']=pd.to_datetime(df['Year_Quarter'].str.replace(' ', ''))+pd.offsets.QuarterBegin(startingMonth=1)
```

However, I got the following error:

```
      AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: For me it's working, are you sure the dtype is string? (there is a typo, you wrote `de` instead of `df` but I don't think is that)

Comment: Can you try doing `df['Year_Quarter'].astype(str)`?

Comment: Thank you. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the type of your `df` do you mind to add the output of `df.info()`

When I try to reproduce it I don't have any error.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Year_Quarter':
                   {0: '2009 Q1', 1: '2009 Q1', 2: '2009 Q2'}})

df['Year_Quarter'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year_Quarter'].str.replace(' ', ''))
```

```sh
  Year_Quarter
0   2009-01-01
1   2009-01-01
2   2009-04-01
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried df['Year_Quarter'].astype(str) as suggested by Bruno. The code worked.